# Find position of a term in ClueWeb09 corpora

Tags: java

I want to read term from clueweb09 corpora and find its position to check that term is an entity or not based on dataset that was created [here](http://lemurproject.org/clueweb09/FACC1/). They claim they calculate the position based on: 
**" The zero (0) location used for calculating the annotation offsets is the beginning of the HTTP headers*. This is the first byte after the WARC document header."* . 
I calculate the length of each term by calling `term.getBytes().length` function and sum all positions to find the position of the entity. Unfortunately my position is about 400 byte less than the reported position. I calculate position by reading each *warcfile* file based on following code.

```
ArrayList<Integer> pos = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int position=-1;
    String text;
    try{
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("05");
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

    while(true){
        String line= bufferedReader.readLine();
        if(line==null)
            break;
        else
        {
            int index=line.indexOf(word);
            if(index==-1)
                position=position+line.getBytes().length;
            else{
                  int poss= position +index;
                  pos.add(poss);
                  position=position+line.getBytes().length;
            }
        }
    }
    bufferedReader.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Could you please tell me what is the problem(s)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Find a position of the Clueweb dataset terms in byte I used [this code](https://github.com/lemurproject/nopol) which implement the annotation version of this data set [here](http://lemurproject.org/clueweb09/FACC1/). The *lemur.cw.ann.DetectEncoding* class returns the annotation which are not match with clueweb dataset based on their positions. I change that class and *lemur.cw.ann.Matcher* class to calculate the postion of the Clueweb terms based on byte offset.